# Не работает Websocket send. Реализация чата на вебсокетах

Tags: php, чат

Здравствуйте! Сам чат взял на хабре, тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/ 
Вот демка на чат: http://sharoid.ru/chat.html

Поставил на локальный сервер, все работает. Но на хостинге возникла проблема. Захожу по ssh на сервер и запускаю файл логики сервера сокетов командой php server.php затем иду на страницу клиента и вижу строчки:

system: please wait, I try to connect to the server.

system: connection is open

Соединение успешно установлено. Но когда пытаюсь отправить какое либо сообщение то ничего не происходит. Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: У меня тоже кривовато работает... Кстати вот этот более лучше и проще переделать под свои нужды. https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket исходники в конце странички ;)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: При работе с сокетами напрямую, очень важно что бы был **детерминированый** размер пакета, либо пакет заканчивался `\r\n`. При этом и клиент и сервер должны пакеты обрабатывать одинаково - иначе - зависание одного из них или обеих гарантировано. Если не хотите мучатся - используйте библиотеку готового протокола, например http, либо скачайте библиотеку уже готового чата. Сокеты вроде простые, но неполное понимание как они работают - приводит к зависаниям